# configuring ssl on nginx - is this ciphers list up to date?

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have bought a certificate from Comodo and I'm following [an article on their site](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?/Default/Knowledgebase/Article/View/789/37/certificate-installation-nginx) on how to configure the certificate on my nginx. The question is, is this configuration, mainly the ciphers list, up to date?

```
#enables all versions of TLS, but not SSLv2 or 3 which are weak and now deprecated.
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

#Disables all weak ciphers
ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:
DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:
ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:
DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:
ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:
AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:
AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:
!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
```

The article date is July 27 2011 16:28, which is almost four years old...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is pretty decent for it's age.  A site I have found good and informative in regards to web server security is [Cipherli.st](https://cipherli.st) which gives modern configurations for very secure configurations (incompatible with older clients) and also a set of legacy options so you can support older browsers (IE < 9, Android < 2.2 or Java < 6).

When you want to test your configuration to see compatibility with various browsers, supported ciphers, and various security options the [SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) from Qualys is very helpful.

Comment: I got an A on the SSL Server Test mentioned. Guess it is a good enough grade : )

Comment: That is a good indicator you don't have any security issues or weak ciphers.  The other thing to check is that your configuration supports all of the clients you need to support.  You can still achieve an A+ rating when your site is inaccessible to IE < 11 or Android clients.  But if you don't need to support those old browsers, you can disable TLS < 1.2 and only enable strong ciphers.  All depends on your target audience and security requirements.